# sound and preloader is not working in Flash CS6 to HTML5(swiffy)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I create the project in Flash CS6 and tray to publish in HTML5, using the swiffy flash extension. In my project i create some animation, loading and use some sound (.mp3). When I export this to HTML5 (swiffy). I got this kind of output warnings

---

> Swiffy Flash Extension for Win v1.1.1 [Swiffy v5.1.1]
>   - Warnings - Streaming audio is not supported. Support for external resources is experimental. The ActionScript property
>   flash.net.URLLoader.bytesLoaded is not supported. The ActionScript
>   property flash.net.URLLoader.bytesTotal is not supported. The file may
>   be slow.

---

And when I open my html file, loader and sound it’s not working
I use this code for loading

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading); this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);   function onLoading(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
                var loaded:Number = evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal;
                percent_txt.text = (loaded*100).toFixed(0) + "%"; };   function onComplete(event:Event):void {
                this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading);
                this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
                gotoAndPlay(2);   };
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, dont know what u are expecting here!!! The warnings are already telling you quite cleary whats going on. The things you are trying to do are not supportet.
**The correct anwser is:** What you are trying to do, cant be done with swiffy!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); 

function onLoading(evt:ProgressEvent):void { 
  var loaded:Number = evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal;
  percent_txt.text = (loaded*100).toFixed(0) + "%"; 
};

function onComplete(event:Event):void {
  this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading);
  this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); gotoAndPlay(2);
};
```

Were we have to add this code to get audio...